# SVG displays incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, firefox

I have an SVG that I plan to put on a website.

The SVG was generated from illustrator using using the method described [here](https://medium.com/@colinlord/how-to-export-svgs-for-the-web-from-illustrator-829bc1c841f6)

When viewed in Firefox 84.0.1 I get this:
[image: Firefox]

When viewed in Safari 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9) and Chrome 87.0.4280.88 I get this:
[image: Safari - Chrome]

Is this an issue with Firefox or an issue with the SVG?
What's the best way to debug?

**Edit**

I was able to isolate the problem to the following path.  As pointed out by others the issue appears to be with invalid path descriptions in the SVG.

I was able to solve problem by simplifying the path in illustrator and re-exporting.

[image: Original vs. Simplified]

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="138.71" height="102.25" viewBox="0 0 138.71 102.25"><path d="M73.72,95.49a9.59,9.59,0,0,1,5.2,1.3,1990328647664.52,1990328647664.52,0,0,0,.2.2,9,9,0,0,1,3.7,3.8,8.75,8.75,0,0,0,7.7,4.8,8.46,8.46,0,0,0,7.7-4.8A9.27,9.27,0,0,1,102,97c.1-.1.2-.1.3-.2a10.56,10.56,0,0,1,5.2-1.3,8.71,8.71,0,0,0,7.8-4.3,8.39,8.39,0,0,0-.2-8.9,9.55,9.55,0,0,1-1.5-5.2v-.3a9.69,9.69,0,0,1,1.4-5.2,9,9,0,0,0,.3-9.1,8.64,8.64,0,0,0-8-4.3,9.59,9.59,0,0,1-5.2-1.3,2487910809616.32,2487910809616.32,0,0,1-.2-.2,9,9,0,0,1-3.7-3.8,8.75,8.75,0,0,0-7.7-4.8,8.46,8.46,0,0,0-7.7,4.8,9.27,9.27,0,0,1-3.8,3.8c-.1.1-.2.1-.3.2a10.56,10.56,0,0,1-5.2,1.3,8.71,8.71,0,0,0-7.8,4.3,8.39,8.39,0,0,0,.2,8.9,9.55,9.55,0,0,1,1.5,5.2v.3a9.69,9.69,0,0,1-1.4,5.2,9,9,0,0,0-.3,9.1A8.83,8.83,0,0,0,73.72,95.49Z" transform="translate(-61.55 -45.07)" fill="none" stroke="#6d6665" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="6"/><path d="M154.45,95.49a9.11,9.11,0,0,1,5.3,1.4.1.1,0,0,1,.1.1c4.25,2.56,5.31,9,11.4,8.6,6.22.44,7.09-6.08,11.5-8.6s10.63-.31,13.3-5.8c3.54-5.22-1.82-9.29-1.7-14.4,0-4.93,5-9.26,1.7-14.3-2.73-5.6-9-3.13-13.3-5.7a.1.1,0,0,1-.1-.1c-4.25-2.55-5.31-9-11.4-8.6-6.23-.44-7.09,6.09-11.5,8.6s-10.64.31-13.3,5.8c-3.55,5.23,1.81,9.29,1.7,14.4a9.69,9.69,0,0,1-1.4,5.2C142.83,87.73,147.57,96.09,154.45,95.49Z" transform="translate(-61.55 -45.07)" fill="none" stroke="#6d6665" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="6"/><text transform="translate(9.1 84.85)" font-size="12" fill="#231f20" font-family="MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro">O<tspan x="8.27" y="0" letter-spacing="0em">r</tspan><tspan x="12.24" y="0">i</tspan><tspan x="15.05" y="0" letter-spacing="-0.01em">g</tspan><tspan x="21.68" y="0">inal</tspan><tspan x="4.68" y="14.4">32 pts</tspan></text><text transform="translate(84.57 84.85)" font-size="12" fill="#231f20" font-family="MyriadPro-Regular, Myriad Pro">Simplified<tspan x="9.92" y="14.4">15 pts</tspan></text></svg>
```

Comment: unless you provide the markup (ideally minimised) it's impossible to tell.

Comment: The svg code is quite long.  I'm put the file here : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=53854733358892259394

Comment: Your paths aren't valid/sensible they contain huge values such as 829303603150 If you used illustrator to create this then you'd better report that as an illustrator bug.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks. Strange it’s working in any browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the start of one of the paths in question:

```
M 279.17, 522.38
a 9.59, 9.59, 0,0,1, 5.2,1.3,
a 497582161915.69, 497582161915.69, 0,0,1, 0.2, 0.2,
a 9, 9, 0,0,1, 3.7, 3.8,
```

`M` is a Move path command.  `a` means draw a elliptical Arc.

The first two numbers in the arc command are the X and Y radii of the ellipse.  Somehow that second arc has ended up with an enormous radius.

With an radius that large, you could approximate a small section of it with a straight line.  That is probably what Chrome and Safari are doing.  However Firefox is clearly getting confused by values that large.

How that arc ended up like that, I have no idea.  But it appears you have struck an edge case that FF isn't handling very well.

I would suggest reporting it as an Illustrator bug and possibly a FireFox bug.  In the meantime, to work around the problem, you would need to edit those shapes and try and fix those faulty arc segments.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  I updated my question with more information and a workaround.  This is clearly an illustrator bug.